# css grouping selectors

Tags: css, css-selectors

Without grouping we could do:

```
.footer_content a:link {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
.footer_content a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

With grouping:

```
.footer_content a:link, .footer_content a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

is there a way to define the css selector to get rid of the extra .footer_content declaration that does the same thing?  Something that would looking a bit like this:

```
.footer_content (a:link, a:visited) {
    color: #FFFFFF;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve something kinda similar with [Sass](http://sass-lang.com/), which "compiles down" to CSS.

In Sass you would use nesting, like so:

```
.footer_content {
  a:link, a:visited {
    color: #FFFFFF;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is convenient, I wish it was standard css!

Answer (score 4):

There currently is not a universally supported way of achieving that.

However, the experimental [`:any()` selector](http://hacks.mozilla.org/2010/05/moz-any-selector-grouping/) would make that possible, if it gets implemented and standardised. It is not supported in any browser but the latest Firefox nightlies yet.